# Save input text filed containing double quoted data to a text file

Tags: php, double-quotes

I have 2 input field, `name` and `height`. When i submit it, I want to save it to a text file.

```
$name = $_POST['name'];     // Michel
$height = $_POST['height']; // 5'4"    

$text = $name."\n".$height;
file_put_contents('test.txt', $text);
```

When i save it, there are back slashes in the height. I remove them using:

```
 $text = $name."\n".stripslashes($height);
 $text = $name."\n".strislashes($height);
```

But I'm not quite sure if this is the correct way to do it. Is there a better way to accomplish the same thing?

Comment: What would leave you to believe that there's a better way?

Comment: Because there is? Disable the "magic quotes" PHP setting